# Git and Xcode: Why do I have to agree to Xcode's T&Cs to use Git?

Tags: xcode, git

Git temporarily stopped working after I updated Xcode on my Mac. The message:

"Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo."

and then started working once I'd agreed to Xcode's T&Cs and installed the update.

Why, or should I say how, are the two linked?

I installed Git using the install.

Comment: Same question here. I was a bit startled when this command: `$ git status` refused to run and issued this output: `Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.` I don't even use Xcode (just the command line tools for builds).

Comment: You should probably ask Apple this. Unless an XCode dev is on Stackoverflow, I doubt you'll get a conclusive answer.

Comment: Your git binary is provided by XCode (which is an easy way to get many command line tools).  If  you don't like this, you can install it manually.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: That'd make sense. The Git manual even recommends that way of installation on a Mac. I can't remember how I installed Git (in 2014) - I would have expected using Homebrew or a separate Git installer. I suspect if I'd used XCode specifically to install Git the message would have made more sense at the time. I see Atlassian recommend using a Git for Mac installer from https://sourceforge.net/projects/git-osx-installer/files/. But I did have XCode installed and clearly that's the link.

Comment: @Anthony  Personally I try to stay so close to what Apple thinks I should do as possible (makes many things easier) and the git binary in XCode is "good enough"(TM) for me so the single accept button occasionally is fine with me.  Others may have other needs.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your git binary is provided by XCode (which is an easy way to get many command line tools packaged and maintained by Apple), and Apple wants you to accept their license before using any XCode component

If you don't like this, you can install it manually using Homebrew or similar.  If you want to compile it yourself you will need a compiler for that.  An easy way is using the one provided by XCode (see a pattern here?).

I've found that for my needs as a cross-platform Java-using-git developer the binaries provided by XCode are fine.  This especially since they are automatically updated by Apple over time.

Answer (score 9):

`sudo xcodebuild -license` will show you the license text of Xcode.

You have to agree its terms and condition at the end or you can just run the command given below.

```
sudo xcodebuild -license accept
```

P.S.- You are giving access to xcode.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr try opening xcode and installing the plugins it suggests.

Even after I installed xcode, accepted the terms, and followed the developer tools prompt, it would continue to prompt me to install developer tools as if I didn't just do it. I eventually found a thread on reddit that suggested opening xcode and going through the recommended plugin installtion that comes up and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

After updating XCode, I immediately faced this issue.

I accepted the licence agreement with the below piece of code.

```
sudo xcodebuild -license accept
```

Answer (score -2):

In your terminal, run your git command as sudo

```
sudo git status
```

This will give you the option to view/accept the license agreements. Press enter to view it and press space until you get to the bottom. You can then type "agree" to agree to the license agreements. This will get rid of that message and you can use git again.

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful to know, but the question was "how" are they linked?

Answer (score -2):

Run

```
sudo git status
```

on your terminal.
After this, It will say that you have not agreed to the agreement and press <kbd>return</kbd> to show the agreement.

Press <kbd>return</kbd>.

It will display the agreement with 'press space' for more.
Press <kbd>space</kbd> to reach the end of the agreement and type agree at last.

Now the problem is resolved.